# How to create a "data base txt" file in Windows Phone project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I know that MS Windows Phone has not nice policy of forbiddings simple saving files on the phone. I want to have one file consisting data which looks like that:

```
//string double
    A 444,0
    B 332,240
    ...
```

This is database of tone corresponding to the frequency in Hz. How to built it into the app so I can read it later. I do not want to create during the run of the app but want it to be created already as a source of data for the app so I can read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the file to your project, and in the properties window for the file, set the **build action** to **Resource**.

In your code, you can retrieve a [StreamResourceInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resources.streamresourceinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instance by calling the [Application.GetResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596994%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method and then reading from it's stream using a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

The path to the file will be "/AssemblyName;component/Folder/File.ext". Where "AssemblyName" is the name of your assembly, and "/Folder/File.ext" is the path to the file relative to your project root. For example.  The following code reads the "/Data/tones.txt" file:

```
private void ReadTones()
{
  string tonesPath = "/PhoneReadFileResource;component/Data/tones.txt";
  Uri tonesUri = new Uri(tonesPath, UriKind.Relative);
  StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(tonesUri);
  StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(sri.Stream);
  TextDisplay.Text = rdr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

You can download a sample project based on your question here: http://sdrv.ms/RnVbQ3

Comment: Please help me I have no idea what path should I use. My solution and project name is Tuner, the file is tunings.txt.

Comment: Assuming the tunings.txt is not in a subfolder of the project, the path should be "/Tuner;component/tunings.txt"

Comment: @BStateham Am I able to write anything into that resource while app is running(update it)?

Comment: @RobertKilar no.  Resources will be static because the are part of the application.  If you want to be able to modify the file, you should use Isolated Storage instead.  You could start by copying the original file from the resource into Isolated Storage the first time the app is run (or if the Isolated Storage file doesn't exist) , and then working with the file in Isolated Storage from that point on.  You can read more about using the IsolatedStorageFile class here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile(v=VS.95).aspx